# How can i configure my Expression Language to work in eclipse while also using JSP/JSTL? Just JSP?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jstl

This is my original post.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079182/is-not-working-on-my-jsp-page-how-can-i-get-my-html-tag-to-work-again?noredirect=1#comment109801916_62079182](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFZCD.jpg)

I've have read the contents and tried multiple things.

I believe what's occurring is my JSTL has its own EL ${} tag, and my JSP has its own EL ${} tag. I feel like they are colliding making the memory space null or cleared.

Question: How can I configure Eclipse to accept one and disable the other?

Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't my current version 4.0 using Dynamic Web Project. Does this only work in Maven Projects?

Is jstl-1.2.jar using a strict version dynamic web project? Is this the issue? Should I go down to Dynamic Web Project 3.0? Or even 2.5? Should I get a different jar file?

Once again I'm a junior software developer trying to understand why my jar file isn't working properly in comparison to the JSP in my dynamic web project. Please be gentle :D

This is to show you what is happening when I run from the server.

[This is when isELIgnored="true"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFZCD.jpg)

[This is when isELIgnored="false"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq631.jpg)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<c:forEach items="${students}" var="s" >
     ${s} <br/>
</c:forEach>



</body>
</html>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
                                                                                                                                                            <!--"http://xmlns.jcp.orb/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5"-->
  <display-name>JSTLexample</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


 <!--   *** This does nothing diffrent***
     <jsp-config>
         <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <el-ignored>false</el-ignored> 
        </jsp-property-group>
     </jsp-config>

--> 
</web-app>
```

```
package com.Demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/DemoServlet")
public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet{

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        //String name = "Navin";

        List <Student> studs = Arrays.asList(new Student(1, "brandon"), new Student(2, "Micheal"), new Student (3, "Charles"));

        request.setAttribute("students", studs);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("display.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

```
package com.Demo;

public class Student {
    int rollno;
    String name;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [rollno=" + rollno + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }


    public int getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }


    public void setRollno(int rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Student(int rollno, String name) {
        super();
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to the issue is I need to run it from the servlet because for some reason we don't run it from the JSP. As of right now don't run JSP unless your doing HTML changes. Always run from servlet being that they communicate between one and another.